# How to read .npy file in Mathematica?

Tags: export, import, dataset, list-manipulation, python

I have a `.npy` file which is created by numpy of Python as below:-

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(60)
y=x.reshape(3,4,5)
np.save("C:\\Users\\H42\\Desktop\\matrix001.npy", y)
```

I tried to read this in Mathematica, and thus I used:-

```
data = BinaryReadList["C:\Users\H42\Desktop\matrix001.npy"];
data
```

However, the output is not what I want. The original matrix is just integers from 0 to 59, with size 3x4x5. But the matrix that I got in Mathematica is totally different, with size 368... Why and what should I do?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you are able to change the original python code, you could also use no.savetxt() to save as a text file that is easily read by MMA. If you’re stuck with a .npy file, the solutions below are much better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I got the files from somewhere else so I can't save it as the format I want. I can import it in Python first and then converted to another format, but that would be better if I can read it in Mathematica directly.

Comment: No worries, I figured you probably wouldn't be asking if np.savetxt() was an option, but thought I'd mention it just in case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked on Linux.

```
str = Import["matrix001.npy", "String", Path -> NotebookDirectory[]];
meta = Flatten@StringCases[str, "{" ~~ __ ~~ "}"];

dims = Flatten@StringCases[meta,
    "(" ~~ z__ ~~ ")" :> ToExpression["{" <> z <> "}"]];
nElems = Times @@ dims;
sizeOfInteger = 8 (* bytes *);

binData = StringTake[str, -sizeOfInteger*nElems ;;];
bstream = StringToStream[binData];
raw = BinaryReadList[bstream, "Integer64"];

On[Assert]
Assert[Length[raw] == nElems, 
     "Did not read the correct number of integers"]
Close[bstream];

data = ArrayReshape[raw, dims]
```

The idea is to read the entire file as a string.  The beginning of the string is text metadata, including the array dimensions.  The binary data follows.  The code parses out the dimensions, but assumes the data is 8-byte integers, but that could have been parsed out also.  Then the code reads the end of the string as a binary stream and reshapes the list into the original shape.

It's completely experimental, but seems to work in this case.

Comment: The format is specified [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/format.py).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Windows 10. I tried the above code but it failed at the first line `str = Import["C:\Users\H42\Desktop\matrix001.npy", "String", Path -> NotebookDirectory[]];`. What documentation can I look at so that I can fix this line for Windows?

Comment: Try it without the `Path-> ...` option, since the path is already in your filename.

Comment: It doesn't work in Windows. `str` is just `NUMPY\.00v\.00{'descr': '<i4', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (3, 4, 5), } ` and some unrelated characters... but many thanks for help!

Comment: Your header contains '<i4'.  That's important information.  It means numpy wrote 4-type integers.  My numpy wrote 8-byte integers.  You must change `sizeOfInteger` to 4 and change the binary element type to "Integer32", for 32 bits.  My file is 608 bytes long.  That's 128 bytes for the header and 480 bytes for the data.  Your file is 368 bytes long, which is 128 bytes for the header and 240 bytes for the data.

Comment: It works! So what I did is to remove `Path -> NotebookDirectory[]`, use `sizeOfInteger = 4` and `raw = BinaryReadList[bstream, "Integer32"];`. I have learnt a lot from this example. But I am so curious: `binData` are still lots of irrelevant characters (while `head@binData` really tell me that `binData` is just a simple string), but `raw` give me the data? Why is that? Many thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest reading it with numpy and not Mathematica. It seems to me that this is not an exchange format. It is a format meant to be used only by numpy.

Mathematica 12.0 has significantly improved `ExternalEvaluate`, and now you can transfer data from Python to Mathematica quite efficiently.

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python",
 "import numpy as np
 x = np.arange(60)
 y=x.reshape(3,4,5)
 y"
]
```

[image]

```
Normal[%]
(* {{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, {15,
    16, 17, 18, 19}}, {{20, 21, 22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27, 28, 
   29}, {30, 31, 32, 33, 34}, {35, 36, 37, 38, 39}}, {{40, 41, 42, 43,
    44}, {45, 46, 47, 48, 49}, {50, 51, 52, 53, 54}, {55, 56, 57, 58, 
   59}}} *)
```

Comment: Seems doesn't work for Mathematica 11.3. I will test it again on Mathematica 12 once it's available to me. Thanks!

Comment: @H42 It requires Mathematica 12.0.