# How to make Mathematica read in CSV as fast as Python's Pandas

Tags: performance-tuning, import, python, csv-format

I have many big CSV files for processing in Mathematica.
And each time loading them into Mathematica takes a long time.
Meanwhile, it takes much less time using [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) under [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29).

For example, Mathematica takes much longer to import this test file ([download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ci2kep1n1kftuc/test.csv?dl=0)) than Pandas:

```
fn = "/Users/sunt05/Dropbox/Public/test.csv";

(*Mathematica*)
ds = Import[fn, "Dataset", "HeaderLines" -> 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{7.48445, Null}*)

(*Pandas*)
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
py = ExternalEvaluate[session];
py[StringTemplate["import pandas as pd; res=pd.read_csv('``')"][fn]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.966052, Null}*)
```

So, **how can we build a fast CSV reader in Mathematica?**

---

Edit:

Thanks folks for the interests!

For using `Dataset` in the comparison, I just wanted to make the comparison more fair from the user perspective with respect to functionality: `Dataset` seems more analogous to `pandas.DataFrame` if a user wants to further process the imported data.

Comment: Using `OpenRead` with `ReadLine` to store the header and then call `ReadList` yields a 55% speedup, but it is not as fast as pandas unfortunately.

Comment: Sadly, `Dataset` is rather inefficient in my experience, and simply unsuitable for working with large data.

Comment: As far as I know there is a new Typesystem in the works which makes Dataset a magnitude faster. It was supposed to be in 12.2 by enabling a switch but unfortunately hasn't made it yet. There is a WTC2020 talk about it.

Comment: @Szabolcs I largely agree with you on the inefficiency of `Dataset`. However, two things we may note here: 1. `Dataset` may facilitate further processing once constructed thought with considerable overhead in the construction; 2. performance in `Dataset` has been noticeably improved in v12.3. So, overall I consider `Dataset` an ~acceptable structure for data processing now (i.e., since v12.3). PS, I used to be strongly against `Dataset` but did love its claimed features.

Comment: @Philipp, yes, it looks very promising but is [still missing in v12.3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216746/user-interface-mathematica-12-1-terribly-slow#comment620892_218930).

Comment: @sunt05 I didn't know that there were performance improvements in 12.3. I will give Dataset another go then as I agree that it convenient. The problem was not functionality but performance.

Comment: @Szabolcs I would not hold my breath here, for changes which would only affect the type system. One of the biggest sources of inefficiency for `Dataset` is that it is row-oriented, and therefore can't effectively use the type information to both store data efficiently and manipulate it faster. The other is generality: `Dataset` does not have a well-defined and restricted query language, but instead allows pretty much all WL functions as parts of its query. This gives it a lot of power, but this at the same time severely limits its efficiency. Both these issues are unlikely to change soon.

Answer (score 11):

I think you've actually answered the question yourself - which is to say, perhaps just use pandas with [`ExternalEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html)?

The answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197084/41179) and the ["Python" External Evaluation System guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/Python.html) suggest that data can be transferred quite efficiently back to Mathematica (at-least in the case of numpy arrays, but the cost of converting should be manageable).

So we can do something like this:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ds2 =
   ExternalEvaluate["Python",
    "
import pandas as pd
res=pd.read_csv('/home/george/Downloads/test.csv')
res.to_numpy()
"];]
{1.28181, Null}
```

This is indeed much faster than `Import`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ds = Import["/home/george/Downloads/test.csv", "HeaderLines" -> 1];]
{5.93136, Null}
```

PS your "Dataset" format specification was part of the timing discrepancy above, so perhaps a slightly unfair comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I put `Dataset` as import type intentionally as `pandas` would read in a CSV as `DataFrame`, a counterpart of `Dataset` in python, so we have a ~fair comparison.

Comment: @sunt05 A `Dataset` is something quite different.  Look at its `FullForm`.

Comment: thanks @Alan. I understand they are structurally different but just wanted to compare them from the user perspective with respect to functionality: `Dataset` seems more analogous to `pandas.DataFrame` if a user wants to further process the imported data.

Answer (score 6):

If we limit the solution scope to Mathematica (e.g., without using `python`, or other `External`-like approaches), it seems `Read`/`ReadList` is the only way to go.

Below is my attempt to finish this task, which can deal with mixed types of elements (e.g., mixture of string, real, integer, etc.):

```
Clear[readCSV]
readCSV[fn_String?FileExistsQ]:=
Module[{str,sample,listHeader,listData,pattern,pre,len,res},
str=OpenRead[fn];
sample=Read[str,{Record,Record}];
{listHeader,listData}=ImportString[StringRiffle[sample,"\n"],"CSV"];
pattern=(Head/@listData)/.{String->Word,Integer->Number};
pattern=Riffle[pattern,Character];
Close[str];
str=OpenRead[fn];
Skip[str,Record];
res=ReadList[str,pattern,WordSeparators->{ ","}][[All,1;;;;2]];
Close[str];
res=Prepend[res,listHeader];
res
]
```

and some simple profiling:

```
ds3=readCSV[fn]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{3.016329`,Null}*)
```

Profiling results of other approaches:

- `Import`:

```
ds = Import[fn, "Data", "HeaderLines" -> 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{7.85502`,Null}*)
```

- `pandas`:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
py = ExternalEvaluate[session];
ds2 = py[
    StringTemplate["import pandas as pd; df=pd.read_csv('``')"][
     fn]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{1.27804`,Null}*)
```

We can see the `ReadList`-based approach is still behind the `pandas` one but does much better job than `Import`.

PS: I really hope WRI can improve the CSV efficiency in future versions.