# Import strategies for large .txt files ~600MB

Tags: import

I'm quite new to large data processing in Mathematica and got the task to Import and Plot some **.txt measurement data**. The files are very very large ~600 MB and have about 3*E7 lines, I can plot and process these sort of data if they were in small files. There I `Import` the file, read the lines, arrange a table and plot it using `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`, maybe I smoothen the plots with a slicing command of every n-th line (skip every n-th line  of the data in the plot). My data processing now takes hours, about 27 minutes per file, and more comming soon!
I import the files with the following command right now, where "names" are the selected files in the directory:

```
names = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", FileNameJoin[{directory}]];

data = Import[names, {"TSV", "Data"}, NumberPoint -> ","];
```

In other posts I found the `ReadList` command... My problem is now that I can't deal with these Input streams. Further i would like to plot the data accurately, because i never used the ImportStream command.
The files are composed out of one header line and 3 columns of values (using a "," as decimal separator) like shown below (i need to use the 2nd as the x-axis data and the 3rd column as the y-axis data). Here is some of the data to give you an idea what the structutre looks like:

t   d   delta_Tw

0,0200  0,0690  1,3296

0,0400  0,0694  1,4288

0,0600  0,0697  1,5167

0,0800  0,0698  1,5304

0,1000  0,0698  1,5200

0,1200  0,0698  1,5095
Due to the large amount of lines maybe a `MovingAverage` Line can be plotted as a "trend line", here the first few lines are shown in the "settle time" of the system, after that short time the system starts to oscillate.

[image]

I hope you can provide some help how i can import these huge files and give me some advice how to process these data as fast as possible. It  would be nice if you can give me some advice but solely in Mathematica, which will be our tool of choice and help me with some specific code examples what would be very helpful  :)!

Comment: It seems you are dealing a large CSV file so this post might be useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249425/260

Comment: What do you mean by "a slicing command of every x-th line" ? Let's say you can read in the first 100 lines of data, is it sufficient to plot something? Could you please add that minimum sized sample and create a representative plot to show what you exactly want? Right now the question is a bit vague.

Comment: Another option is to load the data files into a database. Mathematica works great with databases and often you can let the database do some of the initial processing.

Comment: Can you parallelize processing multiple files at once via the various Parallel options available assuming you have multi-core machine?  This cut the time by about 4 on a quad-core.  Maybe set up ParallelTable to do multiple files simultansously.

Comment: some specific code examples would be very helpful

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide the following: *minimum example of working code *sample data *a plot to show what your end result should look like. This does not mean that you have to post the real data, if it is confidential or for whatever other reason. Just create some data in the same format, and make a plot out of this and post everything here.

Comment: The post includes timing details (meaning it works) and then seeks code without having included a minimal working example so far. Is the question about reading large data files or is it about list processing or plotting is not clear. The "WHOLE DATA" from several million lines would not be a pretty sight or a useful one assuming that the task finishes before a kernel crash. As such, this question cannot be answered as it lacks focus, clarity and needs additional details.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't deal with these Input streams"?

Comment: i would need some examples how to plot the data out of these streams or how to process the import stream out of a txt file

Answer (score 3):

In fact your files are not that large, simply txt format is inefficient for the data storage. You mention 30 millions lines containing 3 floating point numbers. If you store them in a binary format assuming double precision

$$3\cdot10^7\times 3 \times 8 /2^{20} = 687\text{MB}.$$

This is very close to 600MB that you mention. But reading your post I realize that your data does not have the precision of 15 digits (double precision). If one uses single precision for the storage,

$$3\cdot10^7\times 3 \times 4 /2^{20} = 343\text{MB}$$

required. Furthermore, I noticed that your data is equal spaced. This brings us to

$$3\cdot10^7\times 2 \times 4 /2^{20} = 229\text{MB}.$$

Thus, my recommendation is to store everything in a binary format.

```
a = {{0.0200, 0.0690, 1.3296}, 
     {0.0400, 0.0694, 1.4288}, 
     {0.0600, 0.0697, 1.5167}, 
     {0.0800, 0.0698, 1.5304}, 
     {0.1000, 0.0698, 1.5200}, 
     {0.1200, 0.0698, 1.5095}};

fileIn = "~/Documents/debug.dat"
(* prepare some binary file *)
(* this part should be done with some other program *)
str = OpenWrite[fileIn, BinaryFormat -> True]
BinaryWrite[str, Dimensions[a] // Last, "Integer32"]
Do[BinaryWrite[str, z, "Real32"], {z, a}];
Close[str]
```

It is assumed that at this point there is a large binary file `~/Documents/debug.dat` with all the data. After that you can use the following strategy

```
(* open a data file in binary format *)
str = OpenRead[fileIn, BinaryFormat -> True]
(* read a header indicating the structure of the data, e.g. number of records and columns *)
(* depending on your needs you may or may not need such a header *)  
dim = BinaryRead[str, "Integer32"]
(* read all data at once *)
data = BinaryReadList[str, "Real32"];
(* verify if your data has correct dimensions*)
Dimensions[data]
(* finalize *)
Close[str]
```

Now do the plots

```
data2D = Partition[data, dim];
ListPlot[data2D[[All, {1, 2}]]]
```

Comment: You might be right, if there were just 3 columns, in fact there are also time formated columns, but our interest is just for 3 of them. And after that i can simply plot the data with the known Plot[data] command?

Comment: @ChristophBleicher Just update your post with a short example of your data in normal txt format. You can have just 5 rows instead of 30000000. This would be enough for illustration. One can further read txt in your way and save as binary for illustration. In real world you can save your data directly in binary format or use some scripting language (perl, python) to convert to the binary format.

Comment: should i upload it directly or is there a possibility to share it with you?

Comment: i thought it would not be possible to import  a .txt file in the post

Comment: i see, now i gave a short example to copy into a notepad text file or whatever...

Comment: Thanks, that wil help me a lot!

Comment: Is there a feature to handle also a date column, different headers and more columns as well? Will the binarywrite  command also work?

Comment: @ChristophBleicher Why are you interested in the `BinaryWrite`? You do not need to create the binary file with MA. This was just an example. I am suggesting to save your data in a binary format from the beginning. If it is not possible, you can use some scripting language (perl, python) to convert to the binary format. Concerning that date, it depends a lot whether this will be (1) a part of the analysis, or (2) it is simply for book-keeping (to be able to say when the measurement has been made). In (1), you can save the number of milliseconds after the midnight as long integer or double.